# Proving that $\sin(x) = o(1)$ & $\sin(x) = O(x)$.

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

A theorem I am given states that a function $f(x) = p_n(x) + O((x-x_0)^{n+1})$ where $p_n(x)$ is the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ without the remainder error term.

I have a few questions to prove using this theorem and the first two are as follows:

$\sin(x) = o(1)$ as $x \rightarrow 0 $

$\sin(x) = O(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0 $

This is my first introduction to Landau's notation. I understand, at least I think I do, the concept behind "big o" and "little o" and I have the notes for the notation means. However, I couldn't find any questions that satisfied the use of that theorem.

For the first one I tried taking the Taylor expansion to say and using the theorem I got that $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + O((x)^6)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ but I couldn't get any further than that.
I also tried taking the other angle and starting with $\sin(x) = o(1) \Rightarrow \sin(x) = O(1)$ which means that $\lvert \sin(x)\rvert \le C \lvert 1\rvert$

Could anyone please try to help me through at least the first one? I'm little lost on exactly what I'm trying to do here.

EDIT: I probably should have clarified that the question is asking that those two relations are proven using the theorem I put at the top of this question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use it for $n=0$ and $n=1$

Comment: What does $o(1)$ mean?

Comment: @AleTolcachier ah, I think I see what you mean. Are you saying that for the polynomial degree 0 I would simply have $\sin(x) = 0 + O(x^1)$?

Comment: @copper.hat the $o(1)$ is the asymptotic notation. It means that if $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\lvert f(x) \rvert}{\lvert g(x)\rvert}$ = 0

Comment: @ArranSykes Yes, to use your theorem. Nevertheless, I think that it's easier to use simply the limits $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that thank you. That is the confusing part though because the question explicitly asks for it to be proven using the theorem. Though, I do have a better understanding of the limits as well now.

Comment: @ArranSykes: What is your g(x) here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

For the first one: saying a function $f$, defined in a neighbourhood of $0$,  is $o(1)$ simply means that $\lim_{x\to  0} f(x)=0$.

For the second one, saying that   $f(x)=O(x)$ means that  $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=O(1)$, i.e.  is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$ (except at $0$, where it is undefined).

Comment: For that second hint is it O(1) because it is a constant? Also, sorry, I'm unsure how to work that into using the theorem? I think I understand the limits and what you're saying it's just using the theorem that is confusing me

Comment: It is $O(1)$ because it is actually $\dfrac{O(x)}{x}=O\Bigl(\dfrac{x}{x}\Bigr)=O(1)$. More generally, $\dfrac{O(x^\alpha)}{x^\beta}=O\Bigl(\dfrac{x^\alpha}{x^\beta}\Bigr)=O(x^{\alpha-\beta})$.